# Android overlay errors - what do they mean?

Tags: android, popupwindow

When I run my application the logcat is being flooded with the below error messages which I could not understand. Messages appear when `PopupWindow` is shown or dismissed. What do they actually mean?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these are errors from your app?

Comment: could you post some code where the errors are given?

Comment: @Dediqated Actually I can not identify what part of code produces these errors. That is why I put this question here, I want to find it out. Application works well as expected. Only that I get errors in the log cat every time I interact with the application so I know the errors are somehow related to it.

Comment: @AleksG No, I am not sure. But they are certainly related to it.

Comment: I think you have installed the [OVInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.skywave.ovinfo) app installed and that's giving debugging log

Comment: @Dediqated No I do not have that installed.

Comment: Try disabling some settings in Developer settings, those could give the logs. According to [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/display/+/8e1ae95d9dd49199bba1d7343ac7ffb842ddd10b/liboverlay/overlayMdp.cpp) I think it has to do something with your screen (overlay)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the DDMS GUI version of logcat, you can easily see what application the log entries are coming from. You can also get this information by running `adb logcat -v long`, but it takes a bit more cross referencing (ie the PID) to easily see the app name.

[image]

Comment: I added my LogCat screenshot to the question. I assume error messages are coming not from my application because Application column is empty and I see some other informational and debug messages with my application name in it.

Comment: no, those are definitely not coming from your application, they are related to HW overlay, might be able to make them go away by disabling developer options, but personally I would just ignore.